# How to pass javascript function as a parameter in the route values of Ajax Actionlink

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I need to pass javascript function as a parameter value to the ajax actionlink in asp.net mvc app. how can we achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can pass javascript functions in **Route Values**! Are you sure this is exactly what you meant?